# How to fix UIViews programmatically in both Portrait and LandScpae modes

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Hi i am beginner in ios and i my `ViewController` i have added Two  `UIViews` programmatically they are "MyFisrtView"  and "MySecondView"

And also i have added two Button they are NEXT button and BACK buttons and when i click NEXT button i move first `UIView` to second `UIView` using animations and when i click BACK button i return back to second `UIView` ti first `UIView`

Here my main problem i when i change my simulator orientation at **Portrait** to **LandScpae** screen is divided like two parts as like my below image why i got this problem can any body help me please

### my code:-

### mainViewcontroller:-

```
#import "MainViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController (){

    UIView * MyMainView;
    SubViewController * Sv;

}
@end

@implementation MainViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    MyMainView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    MyMainView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    MyMainView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [self.view addSubview:MyMainView];

    Sv = [[SubViewController alloc]init];
    [Sv createViewView:MyMainView];
}
@end
```

### SubViewClass:-

```
  #import "SubViewController.h"

    @interface SubViewController (){

        UIButton * GoNext;
        UIButton * GoBack;

        UIView * MyFisrtView;
        UIView * MySecondView;
        UIView * MainView;
    }
    @end

    @implementation SubViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad {

        [super viewDidLoad];
    }

    -(void)createViewView :(UIView*)mainView{

        MainView = mainView;

        MyFisrtView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, MainView.frame.size.width, MainView.frame.size.height)];
        MyFisrtView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        MyFisrtView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
        [MainView addSubview:MyFisrtView];

        MySecondView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, MainView.frame.size.width, MainView.frame.size.height)];
        MySecondView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        MySecondView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        [MainView addSubview:MySecondView];

        GoNext = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 100, 30)];
        [GoNext setTitle:@"Next" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [GoNext addTarget:self action:@selector(GoNext:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        GoNext.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        [MyFisrtView addSubview:GoNext];

        GoBack = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 100, 30)];
        [GoBack setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [GoBack addTarget:self action:@selector(GoBack:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        GoBack.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
        [MySecondView addSubview:GoBack];

        MyFisrtView.hidden = NO;
        MySecondView.hidden = YES;
    }

    -(void)GoNext:(id)sender{

        MySecondView.hidden = NO;

        MySecondView.frame = CGRectMake(MyFisrtView.frame.size.width, 0, MainView.frame.size.width, MainView.frame.size.height);   // starting visible position

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                              delay:0.0f
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                         animations:^{

                             [MySecondView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, MainView.frame.size.width, MainView.frame.size.height)];   // final visible position

                         }
                         completion:nil];
    }

    -(void)GoBack:(id)sender{

        MySecondView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, MainView.frame.size.width, MainView.frame.size.height);   // starting visible position

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                              delay:0.0f
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                         animations:^{

                             [MySecondView setFrame:CGRectMake(MyFisrtView.frame.size.width, 0, MainView.frame.size.width, MainView.frame.size.height)];    // final visible position
                         }
                         completion:nil];
    }

    @end

-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait){
        NSLog(@"portrait");
    }
    else if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        NSLog(@"LandscapeRight");

        MyFisrtView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, MainView.frame.size.width, MainView.frame.size.height);
    }
    else if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        NSLog(@"LandscapeLeft");

        MyFisrtView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, MainView.frame.size.width, MainView.frame.size.height);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you create views programmatically but not add any autolayout constraint or auto resizing constraint to them so once you set myFirstView width and height like superView width , height as ex. 320 and 480... it remains same when you change it to landscape mode... so to adjust them in landscape mode you have to again reset their height and width. you can do it programmatically or can set constraint on them.

for programmatically change their size you can do it like this

```
-(void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationisLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation))
     {
          myFirstView.frame.size.widht = superView.frame.size.height;
          myFirstView.frame.size.height = superView.frame.size.widht;
     }
     else
     {
                  myFirstView.frame.size.widht = superView.frame.size.width;
          myFirstView.frame.size.height = superView.frame.size.height;
     }
}
```

Comment: how can i set them please can you update my code because i am very begginer

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with auto layout, then add constraint for view programatically. Otherwise try following

If you are using iOS 8.0 and earlier, then implement following method and update your views frame for orientation.

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    MyFisrtView = CGRectMake(0, 0, MainView.frame.size.width, MainView.frame.size.height);
    // ........ And so on
}
```

If you are using iOS 9.0 and onwards then implement respective method, and do update your code respectively

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id <UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    // Your code
}
```

Comment: see i update my code with your answer but not working

Comment: and more ever willRotateToInterfaceOrientation method is not calling in my sub class